# Little Annabel Weights

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> When the wind blows, I may shout and jeer
>   Or OP's no-no perhaps you may hear.
>   I may surround footwear
>   Or cook up that tramp there!
>
> When the wind blows, I may concern tights.
>   Maybe (hope not) some lad's in their sights.
>   A cutie is leaving
>   And sighs she is heaving!
>
> But when the wind's calm, they float in for the night.
>   A snake is with you when you point lower right.
>   I'm a shed by the bed. Can you guess? You just might

The answer is a single English word.

**Hint**

> When the wind’s calm, the holy tree leads.
>  One kilo proceeds.
>  Next you employ
>  A place for a hoy.

**Extra Hint**

> When you figure out the title, you’ll figure out the wind. When you figure out the wind, you’ll figure out the verses. When you figure out the verses, you’ll figure out the word and, voila, you’re done.
>  Don’t you wish everything was so simple?

**Thoughts**

> Should the calm come before the storm?
>  Was the hint meant to rile you up?
>  P.S. (Lennon’s dream or revolution)

**Rhyme**

> When weights are light and name is short,
>  That Annabel's a tricky sort.
>  Verse three is a clue of a cryptical kind
>  To make sense of the others, you'll have to... un-wind.
>  I tried, but failed to make you smiley
>  By sticking in that hint - a riley.
>  Apologies for this, my poem
>  Regarding that, a crafty hoem.

**Other Thoughts**

> Existence or being is here with his friends.
>  Alternatives aid as this kind of line wends.
>  They may catch y’all if the hearer’s ear bends.
>  Best of all, they have one use: sailors’ ends.

**This Really Is A Hint**

> When I thought about writing the "Other Thoughts" section I intended to nudge you in the direction of the answer without spelling it out. That didn't happen.

Comment: I first thought you were referring to [Annabelle](http://juliesaysso.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Annabelle-movie-2014-800x450.jpg), but the spelling is different. That's good — I don't need to revisit my nightmares (...hopefully).

Comment: Hm. This one isn't such a breeze, even if the extra hint tries to tell us otherwise ...

Comment: @MOehm Perhaps more tornado than breeze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> **boathouse**.
>
>  (I first had "boats" as answer. I found what the 3rd verse describes, but didn't draw the right conclusions. Luckily, Tom did so in the comments and Hugh confirmed his findings.)

The wind:

> The riddle is about anagrams: "When the wind is calm" refers to the original word; "When the wind blows" refers to an anagram of the word.
>
>  The title is a hint towards anagrams: "Little Anabelle" is **ana** and the weights are **grams**.

Third verse:

> This verse describes a **boathouse**: It is a shed by the (river) bed and the boats float in for the night. The middle line is wordplay: **boa** (snake) + **thou** (you) + **se** (lower right on a map).

The hint:

> The hint describes the same word in a Riley-ing fashion: The **bo** tree is holy to Buddhists; **a thou**(sand) is one kilo; to **use** is to employ. A hoy is a small sailing boat.

The thoughts:

> These point us toward solving the "calm" verse first and also to the Riley nature of the hint. John Lennon wrote the songs No 9 Dream and Revolution 9, and boathouse has nine letters.

First two verses:

> Each line describes a possible anagram of **boathouse**. Tom found them all:
>
>  ... I may shout and jeer — **hoot abuse**
>  Or OP's no-no perhaps you may hear. — **hues** ("Hugh's") **taboo**
>  I may surround footwear — **about shoe**
>  Or cook up that tramp there! — **sauté hobo**
>
>  ... I may concern tights. — **about hose**
>  Maybe (hope not) some lad's in their sights. — **shoot beau**
>  A cutie is leaving — **shoo beaut**
>  And sighs she is heaving!  — **beaut oohs**

The rhyme:

> This tells us more explicitly that the poem is a bout a "crafty hoem", that is a home for craft or boats.

The other thoughts:

> This describes boats: Boats are what sailors are needed for and y'all sounds like yawl, catch sounds like ketch. Existence hints at lifeboats.

Comment: Well done! Some more possibilities using your 9 letter answer. 1) hoot abuse, hues taboo :), about shoe, saute hobo 2) about hose, shoot beau ? ,beaut oohs

Comment: Congratulations. The 9 letter answer is indeed the one I was looking for. Perhaps examine again the initial line of "Other Thoughts" (by which I mean the 4th).

Comment: @Tom Well done to you on all of these!

Comment: @Hugh - it took a crafty hoem to solve this, but it inspired me to post a poor riddle about something in the answers.

Comment: The rest of "Other Thoughts" wasn't very good. I was trying to clue other dwellers of the answer: rkvfgrapr -> yvsr, yvar -> ebj jvgu bnef (nygreangvirf) nyfb Xrgpu naq lnjy

Comment: @Tom Ah. And "shoo beaut" for the ?. Not my finest effort.

Comment: @Tom: Ah, that's brilliant! I didn't see that. (I mean I tried to find anagrams of the 9-letter word, but it just didn't make sense to me.) Perhaps you want to post your own answer for the deserved tick?

Comment: For what it's worth, I got the idea of anagrams fairly early on, even if I couldn't make sense of the title until the Rhyme was added. But I thought about winds as answer too long: Annabel Lee (away from wind), a gale (Beaufort 9), which the first line of verse 3 could perhaps transform into a nightingale; Weather (-tight), Water (bed, -shed); breezes ("so simple"). I had a lot of loose scraps that seemed to make sense, but that I couldn't make into a whole. And when I got the third verse today, I still couldn't. Good thing Tom's around. `:)`

Comment: I was baffled by this and delighted you found the answer, only a fragment I thought fit made into a 'Worn out and about' question which would be happy if someone would finish - as it's not great. I missed the boat on this literally as was nowhere near that most important part

Answer (score 8):

Some of this is weak, maybe some others can fill in the blanks.

I think this all has to do with

> Bells

When the wind blows, I may shout and jeer
Or OP's no-no perhaps you may hear.

> Some people don't like the sound of wind chimes.

I may surround footwear

> Bell bottoms

Or cook up that tramp there!

> A bellows helps warm things up.

When the wind blows, I may concern tights.

> Um... [this?](https://www.kbellsocks.com/k-bell-socks-womens-leggings-and-tights.aspx)

Maybe (hope not) some lad's in their sights.

> Bell towers are great for snipers

A cutie is leaving
And sighs she is heaving!

> Tinkerbell

But when the wind's calm, they float in for the night.

> No wind? The wind chimes settle down

A snake is with you when you point lower right. ;-)

> The Rattlesnake is sometimes called a ["Bell Snake"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRTWL0yT_4Q)

I'm a shed by the bed. Can you guess? You just might

> I confess, this one baffles me. Maybe Bell End? :)

Oh and the title:

> Anna**bel**s weights are Dumbbells

Comment: Ingenious! Well worth an upvote. But, sorry, no.

Comment: wow this is incorrect?

Comment: I thought this one had the cat in the bag... turns out it was the dog all along... heheh, whatever that means :P